# C# Receiving using stream reader

Tags: c#, streamreader

Can anyone please give me a tip or guide on how to create a mini program that only receive messages?

I can do a code that can receive but only if I'm sending a message (and I'm expecting a reply)

But how about the program is just waiting?

I got this code on receiving:

```
client.Connect("192.168.1.100",80);
Stream s = client.GetStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
String r = "";
sw.AutoFlush = true;

while(true)
{
    r = sr.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(r);
    Debug.WriteLine(r);
    if (sr.Peek() < 0) break;
}
```

This only work like I said. If I'm sending a message first, then there's a reply.

Comment: It seems you need a Windows Service, for this? You can create a Windows Service to run in background, so every seconds you can connect and check message.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If I understood you correctly: If the program on the machine at 192.168.1.100 that answers your calls on port 80 doesn't send you anything, there won't be anything to read (assuming it is a webserver, you will have to send it something first). So if you want your program to receive data periodically, you will need a server that sends you stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at using a TcpListener object in conjunction with the TcpClient.  [This link](http://blog.theanti9.com/2008/02/13/c-tcplistener-example/) has a good example:

Answer (score 0):

You can use Server Socket that is implemented in TcpListener class, but there are some problem with connecting with this when your computer is in local network.
I think that you should write 3 programms. First which sends messages to serwer, second server which would be placed in always-avaible place in internet -this one would be responsible for enqueue messages, and third one which would ask server for questions.